# Bootstrap left align of 2 rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

i need this result:

```
left row1                                                  right row1
left row2 only on half of width
left row3 only on half of width
```

I try this:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEAN1BSYLNA2

Can you help me with (left row3 only on half of width) position. I need use Bootstrap.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">left row1</div>
  <div class="col-6">right row1</div>
    <div class="col-6">left row2 only on half of width</div>
    <div class="col-6"></div>
    <div class="col-6 ">left row3 only on half of width</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">left row1</div>
        <div class="col-6">right row1</div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line -->
        <div class="w-100"></div>

        <div class="col-6">left row2 only on half of width</div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line -->
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-6">left row3 only on half of width</div>
    </div>
</div>
```